# R Jsonlite - How to iterate a JSON list of objects?

Tags: r, jsonlite

I'm very new in R, but I was tasked with reading a JSON file that looks like the following :

```json
{
  "revisions" : [
    {"number": 1, "description" : "first revision"},
    {"number": 2, "description" : "second revision"},
    {"number": 3, "description" : "third revision"}
  ]
}
```

I need to do some data manipulation iterating over `revisions`, but I can't understand what type of data structure jsonlite is transforming this list into, it seems it transposed it.

This is what I've tried :

```r
json = fromJSON('data.json')
for (revision in json$revisions) {
    print(revision$number) # Doesn't work
    print(revision['number']) # Doesn't work
}
```

How can I read the json file in the way I'm trying above?

Using R 3.6.1, ideally I need to keep it to the base functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json$revisions` is a `data.frame` so you can try something like

```
for (i in seq(nrow(json$revisions))) {
  print(json$revisions$number[i])
}
```